# How to verify if a stream has been copied on a fileSystem

Tags: unit-testing, file-io, mocking, moq

I want to write a unit test that check a stream has been copied on the disk :

The problem is CopyTo method is not virtual so I can't use

```
inputMemoryStreamMock.Verify(c => c.CopyTo(outputMemoryStreamMock.Object));
```

and I don't know how to mock a stream :-/

here is my test method :

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Save_Stream_On_DestinationPath()
    {
        // Arrange
        string fileName = "filename.pdf";
        DateTime date = new DateTime(2013, 9, 27);

        var serverConfigMock = new Mock<IServerConfigurationManager>();
        serverConfigMock.Setup(config => config.ReportingBasePath).Returns(@"c:\reportsFolder");

        var factoryReportFileResultMock = new Mock<IReportFileResultFactory>();

        var timeManagementMock = new Mock<ITimeManagement>();
        timeManagementMock.Setup(c => c.GetServerDate()).Returns(date);

        var fileSystemMock = new Mock<IFileSystem>();
        var fileInfoFactory = new Mock<IFileInfoFactory>();
        var directoryInfoBaseMock = new Mock<DirectoryInfoBase>();
        var inputMemoryStreamMock = new Mock<Stream>();
        var outputMemoryStreamMock = new Mock<Stream>();

        var reportFileHelper = new ReportFileHelper(serverConfigMock.Object, factoryReportFileResultMock.Object, fileSystemMock.Object);


        inputMemoryStreamMock.Setup(c => c.CanRead).Returns(true);
        outputMemoryStreamMock.Setup(c => c.CanWrite).Returns(true);
        outputMemoryStreamMock.Setup(c => c.CanWrite).Returns(true);

        fileSystemMock.Setup(c => c.FileInfo).Returns(fileInfoFactory.Object);
        fileSystemMock.Setup(c => c.File.Create(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(outputMemoryStreamMock.Object);
        fileSystemMock.Setup(c => c.Directory.CreateDirectory(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(directoryInfoBaseMock.Object);
        // Act  
        reportFileHelper.Save(inputMemoryStreamMock.Object, fileName, timeManagementMock.Object);

        // Assert
        inputMemoryStreamMock.Verify(c => c.CopyTo(outputMemoryStreamMock.Object));

    }
```

And here is the method to test :

```
    public void Save(Stream portfolioReportFileInfoBase,  string destinationName, ITimeManagement timeManagement)
    {
        string destinationPath = GetDestinationPath(timeManagement);
        string destinationFileUri = Path.Combine(destinationPath, destinationName);

        FileSystem.Directory.CreateDirectory(destinationPath);

        using (var fileStream = FileSystem.File.Create(destinationFileUri))
        {
            portfolioReportFileInfoBase.CopyTo(fileStream);
        }
    }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My take on a couple of things :

**Readability**

I'm not sure your test reads very nicely. Why do you declare a `fileName` variable as though it were important while you don't even assert on it ? Same goes for `date`. This clutters your test with unneeded detail. Inline values or [Anonymous Variables](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ploeh/archive/2008/11/17/anonymous-variables.aspx?Redirected=true) allow for a better signal/noise ratio.

Then why do you set up `CreateDirectory()` to return something ? You never use that return value, do you ? I suggest you get rid of that and the `directoryInfoBaseMock` variable. Same with `FileInfo` and `fileInfoFactory`. Your test needs to contain the bare minimum to set up the objects you want to verify, and nothing more. If you need to build a deep, complex graph of objects just to test one simple thing, there's generally a problem somewhere.

**Design**

The second thing that raises an alarm is that `Save()` mixes multiple language levels. When you read it, it seems to be at the same time about :

- Portfolios and reports
- Time management
- A lot of lower level filesystem stuff

This is often a sign that an object tries to handle too much, violating the Single Responsibility Principle.

What I would do is distribute these responsibilities across separate objects.

Why does `Save()` need to know about time management ? Sure, we use time management to compute the destination path, but wouldn't it be better aligned with the language level and responsibility level of a `Save()` method if we directly passed it the destination path instead ?

Why does `Save()` need to know about portfolios and reports ? Well, there's basically no reason. You could just rename `portfolioReportFileInfoBase` to... `stream`.

`Save()` and `GetPath()` could then be moved to a separate lower-level filesystem wrapper class (`IFileSystem` is a perfect candidate), removing the tight coupling between `ReportFileHelper` and the filesystem.

Don't try to test that your report is written to the disk using mocks. Do it with an integration test. [Don't mock types you don't own](http://blog.8thlight.com/eric-smith/2011/10/27/thats-not-yours.html). Use mocks only to test how your own classes talk to each other. Wrap external libraries/platforms into wrapper objects, and write integration tests at the boundaries of your application to verify that your wrappers play well with those external libraries/platforms.

Comment: Thank your feedback about readibility... I was too much focus to solve my technical probbem...

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use an isolation framework like TypeMock Isolator or Microsoft Fakes to test this case if you're not willing to change the code of the `Save` method, since `CopyTo` can't be mocked by Moq.

You already encapsulated access to the filesystem behind `IFileSystem`; why not just add a method like `CopyStreamToPath`?

```
public void Save(Stream portfolioReportFileInfoBase,  string destinationName, ITimeManagement timeManagement)
{
    string destinationPath = GetDestinationPath(timeManagement);
    string destinationFileUri = Path.Combine(destinationPath, destinationName);

    FileSystem.Directory.CreateDirectory(destinationPath);
    FileSystem.CopyStreamToPath(portfolioReportFileInfoBase, destinationFileUri);
}
```

and the test:

```
fileSystemMock.Verify(c => c.CopyStreamToPath(inputMemoryStreamMock.object, It.IsAny<string>()));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I use System.IO.Abstractions (http://systemioabstractions.codeplex.com/) which provide IFileSystem interface

Comment: @Florian You could create your own interface subclassing `IFileSystem` and adapter class for the implementation. You could also create a second interface `IFileSystemHelper` or something like that that offers the `CopyStreamToPath` method. Or you could add another paramter to `Save` taking an `Action<Stream, Stream>` with a default of `null` and setting it to `(a, b) => a.CopyTo(b)` if not provided; and in your test, just let it set a flag to know if it was called like `bool copyCalled = False; ...Save(... (a, b) => copyCalled = true); Assert.IsTrue(copyCalled)`.